# Getting an error when trying to create a virtual env

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I want to learn django so I tried to create a virtual env and I am getting this error:

```
mkvirtualenv django

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2881, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 596, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.8.2
```

I haven't used python in a while so i'm not sure what the issue is:

```
 virtualenv --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2881, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 596, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.8.2
```

Comment: What's the output of `virtualenv --version`?

Comment: @ManuelJacob I updated my question with the output.  I am using virutalenvwrapper also in case that matters.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the version of `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` is different from the version in the Python library directory (if it is there in the first place). Can you check in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` if you find anything with the name `virtualenv` in it?

Comment: If you have pip installed, you can try `pip install -U virtualenv`. Does that help?

Comment: @ManuelJacob yes I see ```virtualenv-1.11.6.dist-info  virtualenv_clone-0.2.5-py2.7.egg-info virtualenv.py virtualenv.pyc```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `mkvirtualenv` which is a `virtualenvwrapper` command. You probably do not have `virtualenvwrapper` installed.

Type `virtualenvwrapper` in your command line and observe the input. If you get something like `command not found`, then you should install it first.

You should install it with pip like so `pip install virtualenvwrapper`.

There are some post-installation steps, the most important one being `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` that makes commands like `mkvirtualenv, rmvirtualenv` available.

See `virtualenvwrapper's` [documentation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Alternatively, you can also just make use of `virtualenv`. Check that you have it installed like so

`virtualenv --version`

If you do not, you can install it with `pip`. Once you have it installed, you can create your virtualenv like so
`virtualenv <name>` in the directory of your choice.

Comment: `virtualenvwrapper` is installed obviously. How can `virtualenv` be run (it is run!) when executing `mkvirtualenv` if `virtualenvwrapper` is not installed?

Comment: I have it installed

Comment: @Blankman Try updating your virtualenv installation

`sudo pip install -U virtualenv`

Comment: @ManuelJacob You're totally right! His virtualenv version is really old at `1.8.2` considering that version `15` exists.

Comment: @i_emmanuel That's right. Still this particular error shouldn't happen.

Comment: @ManuelJacob Since he's getting a `DistributionNotFound` error, I'd attempt an update first and see what happens.

Comment: Sure. But the question is why there is a script in `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` that requires an old distribution of virtualenv that is not present.

Comment: @ManuelJacob I think the problem is with this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.6.49. Updating this package might help. That'll probably install that package's dependencies

Comment: `Distribute is a now deprecated fork of the Setuptools` project.`

uninstalling distribute and installing setup_tools, should help